# FDW, replication and CREATE SERVER - will it work?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.3, foreign-data

We have two servers (master, slave) and we want to use the FDW. The two databases to be connected with the FDW are both on the master (and the slave of course).  When we are to `CREATE SERVER` we would run something like:

```
CREATE SERVER server_db2 FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
    OPTIONS (host 'master', dbname 'db2', port '5432');
```

The question is this:  Does the slave create the `server_db2` and connects to the master's IP address?  What will happen if I break the relationship and the slave is promoted to master? I suppose it will be looking for the master to connect right?

Would connecting via 127.0.0.1 and setting the method to something other than `trust` be a safe option?

In general the behavior of the **`postgres_fdw`** is unclear to me in a replicated environment.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really use `postgres_fdw` to connect from a replica server to the master, because you cannot create the foreign server on the replica, it is read only.

You'd have to run the `create` on the master, then rely on it replicating to the read-replica.

Even if you were to do this, it would make no sense. There is no point connecting from a replica to the master, because the replica *has the same data as the master*. There is no purpose to doing this.

Comment: There is a purpose when you lose the master and you promote the slave server.

Comment: @adamo ... in which case you have a FDW pointing to a now-dead master? No, it still makes no sense at all.

Comment: Which is why I am asking about pointing the FDW to 127.0.0.1 and if that would not be wise in such a setup.

Comment: I am not sure from the quesiton, but if the FDW connects to a separate cluster located on the host of the master, it could work (and possibly even make sense).